# Babylon js texture issue when used with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, babylonjs

I'm implementing 3D demo application using Babylonjs library for 3D Demo.I'm importing 3D model from S3 and adding texture image on top of material in Reactjs.
But when i add texture image on top of material, rest of area on 3D model gets black color and i want get rid of it. Code works fine in Babylon playground but fails in React app.

Here is the source code

```
var mat = new BABYLON.CustomMaterial("mat", scene);
    mat.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture(textureImage, scene, false, false);
    materialedMeshes.forEach(mesh => mesh.material = mat);
    mat.emissiveColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 1);
    
    // mat.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 1);
    // mat.specularColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0.5, 0.6, 0.87);
    // mat.emissiveColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 1);
    // mat.ambientColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0.23, 0.98, 0.53);

    mat.diffuseTexture.uOffset = -0.1000;
    mat.diffuseTexture.vOffset = -1.1800;
    mat.diffuseTexture.uScale = 1.2200;
    mat.diffuseTexture.vScale = 2.2200;
    mat.diffuseTexture.uAng = Math.PI;
    mat.diffuseTexture.wrapU = BABYLON.Constants.TEXTURE_CLAMP_ADDRESSMODE;
    mat.diffuseTexture.wrapV = BABYLON.Constants.TEXTURE_CLAMP_ADDRESSMODE;
    mat.Fragment_Custom_Alpha(`
    if (baseColor.r == 0. && baseColor.g == 0. && baseColor.b == 0.) {
        baseColor.rgb = vec3(0.85, 0.85, 0.85);
    }
    baseColor.rgb = mix(vec3(0.85, 0.85, 0.85), baseColor.rgb, baseColor.a);
`)
```